# What can be the Alternative of strlen()?

Tags: c++, string

I found people suggesting not to use **strlen()** giving reason that its time complexity is not **O(1)**.Than what should i use in character array to know the size in good time complexity except

```
     s[i]!='\0'
```

Comment: `std::string::size()`

Comment: You wouldn't use a character array.... and your example doesn't work for determining the size of a C string. Why are you using `char[]` for strings in C++ anyway?

Comment: The problem is not the function (which is implemented as efficient as it can be) but rather the style of coding that makes its frequent use necessary.  As others have mentioned, remember the length of the string.  In C++, use `std::string`.  (You should use it for other reasons too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to use a C-style array of `char`, then I don't think there's any way to work out the length other than by looping through until you get to the end. You can do this yourself or call `strlen`.

However, as you have tagged your question with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), you should be using a `std::string` instead, then you can use the `length` (or equivalently, `size`) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++, don't use C-style strings (i.e. `char*`). Use `std::string` instead. The C++ standard requires `std::string::size` to be of O(1) complexity. It can be achieved by computing the length of the string once and storing it in a data member (and updating if the string length changes).

However, if we are talking about C, then there is no other way. C uses null-terminated strings.

Interestingly, some languages (like Pascal) implement strings differently. Instead of using null-terminated strings (like C does), they opt for length-prefixed strings. It means that each string has its length recorded at the beginning. This has some problems, for example, now you're spending additional bytes to store the length counter, you can only store a finite amount of characters in the string (for example, if you use 2 bytes for length your string may contain at most 2^16 characters), and working with substrings becomes a chore.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from caching the length of a string in a separate variable (preferably encapsulated in some `struct string { char * data; size_t length; size_t capacity; };`) even if you are coding in C.  Some library functions may not allow you to pass that additional information, though.

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, like you said, libraries won't accept the custom structure (most likely they work with simply `char*`s assuming they are `\0`-terminated) and, they may recompute the length of the string again. There isn't 100% sure way to avoid doing that additional work sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a `char[]`, then you can use `sizeof(str) - 1` instead. Note `std::strlen(str)` is likely to be optimized out anyway. For example using GCC 4.9.2 with `-O2`, the following codes:

```
std::cout << sizeof("hello") - 1;
std::cout << std::strlen("hello");
```

result in this assembly:

```
[...]
movl $5, %esi
[...]
```

You should be using `std::string` anyway. `std::string::size` and `std::string::length` both have constant complexity, because it might be implemented like this (libstdc++):

```
  size_type
  size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
  { return _M_rep()->_M_length; }
```

As others have suggested, you can store the length in a variable and minimize the calls to `std::strlen`. In general though, this smells like a case of premature optimization. The C++ standard library is the superior choice, generally.

Answer (score 0):

As someone already mentioned in a comment, you can easily have a structure that holds the Length and the Data like:

```
struct string{
    char * Data;
    int Length;
}
```

You could also have resizeable strings, for which you would also want to hold the capacity.

Either way, you could have both the efficiency of knowing how long it is, and library compatibility. All you need to do is just need to make sure that when you create the string, you make it one byte larger than the length, and make that last byte null. You just need to be careful that this always happens, or else it will cause huge issues.